# Reemplazar valores en un array JSON

Tags: javascript, json, array

Antes que nada muchas gracias por ayudarme! :)
Estoy iniciándome en el mundo de la programación, y hay algo que no estoy pudiendo resolver/entender.
Tengo una web en desarrollo que utiliza Template7, donde básicamente tengo un array en JSON donde sus valores son reemplazados en una página HTML.

Ejemplo:

```
template7Data: {
    datos: [
        {
            id: 01,
            nombre: 'Marcos',
            color: 'azul',
        },
        {
            id: 02,
            nombre: 'Esteban',
            color: 'colorado',
        },
    ],
}
```

En la página web utilizo `{{nombre}}` para agregar los nombres y `{{color}}` para agregar colores, etc.

Código HTML crudo de ejemplo:

```
<p>Bienvenido {{nombre}}. ¡A mi también me gusta el color {{color}}!</p>
```

Código HTML final (cuando carga la web):

```
<p>Bienvenido Esteban. ¡A mi también me gusta el color colorado!</p>
```

Todo funciona de maravillas, pero mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo hacer para reemplazar valores dentro del JSON, antes de que los reemplace en la web?

Por ejemplo, si de repente quiero reemplazar los "colorado" por "rojo" para que al final se lea:

```
<p>Bienvenido Esteban. ¡A mi también me gusta el color rojo!</p>
```

Vale la pena aclarar que tengo un array mucho más extenso, y quisiera cambiar TODOS los valores que sean "colorado" por ejemplo, sin discriminar donde se encuentran.

Espero haya sido lo más claro posible. La verdad que estoy muy perdido. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Mats tu peticion es un poco confusa, dices que quieres reemplazar valores en el json pero tambien dices *sin cambiar los valores en el array*. Quieres que se modifique o no el json?

Comment: Me refería a que no quiero cambiar todo mi documento, sino generar una función que me los reemplace al final. Ahora la edito.

Comment: Tendrías que crear una funcion que reciba como parametro el json, la propiedad y el nuevo valor, recorres el json y vas reemplazando valores.. eso es lo que necesitas por lo que entiendo

Comment: Aún no entiendo cómo hacerlo. Alguien me podría detallar un poco más alguna solución? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Solo quieres poner "rojo" cuando sea "colorado"? o quieres hacer muchos otros mas cambios?

Answer (score 0):

quiza algo asi te ayude:

```
function reempalzar(colorBuscado,nuevoColor){
    template7Data.datos.forEach(function (item){
        if(item.color==colorBuscado){
            item.color=nuevoColor;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Gracias! Ya voy a probar tu sugerencia y te comento si me funciona

Comment: Ok, recuerda marcar +1 si te fue util

Comment: No estoy entendiendo cómo agregar los datos a reemplazar, debería agregar un `var colorBuscado = "colorado"; var nuevoColor = "rojo";` o algo así?

Comment: Invocas la funcion como reemplazar('rojo','colorado')

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer una función que reciba el arreglo de datos, lo recorra y vaya sustituyendo el color original por el nuevo color.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de la función y la manera de llamarla con tus datos de ejemplo

Si haces clic en el botón *Ejecutar* del snippet, va a invocar la función y luego va a imprimir a la consola el JSON completo dónde podrás ver el cambio del color.

```js
let template7Data = {
  datos: [
      {id: 01, nombre: 'Marcos', color: 'azul'}
    , {id: 02, nombre: 'Esteban', color: 'colorado'}
    , {id: 03, nombre: 'Juan', color: 'colorado'}
    , {id: 04, nombre: 'Pedro', color: 'morado'}
  ]
}

function cambiarColor(datos, colorOriginal, nuevoColor) {
  datos.forEach((dato) => {
    if (dato.color == colorOriginal) {
      dato.color = nuevoColor;
    }
  });
}

cambiarColor(template7Data.datos, "colorado", "rojo");
console.log(template7Data);
```